# Como hacer que solo acepte numeros enteros?

Tags: c++, validación, números-enteros

tengo este codigo en c++ sobre cola de datos, pero tengo un problema con la validación, y es que cuando ingreso letras para verificar que solo acepte numeros enteros, se repite indefinidamente y no da oportunidad para ingresar otra opción, intente con un if, pero no funciona, tambien intente con el default y aun así no deja de repetirse. El problema en si, es que no se espera a recibir una nueva instrucción, solo se repite constantemente.

anexo las librerias que ocupé

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int dato;
    Nodo *sig;
};
void insertarCola(Nodo *&, Nodo *&, int);
bool colaVacia(Nodo *);
void supCola(Nodo *&, Nodo *&, int &);

int main(){
    system("color 0a");
    Nodo *frente = NULL;
    Nodo *fin = NULL;
    int to = 0;
    int dato;
    int opc = 0;

do{
    cout<<"--------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------¡Bienvenido!-------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------";
    cout<<"\nPrograma de colas";//Se le proporciona al usuario opciones
    cout<<"\nIngrese una opcion";
    cout<<"\n1. Ingresar datos";
    cout<<"\n2. Desplegar/Eliminar datos";
    cout<<"\n3. Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cin>>opc;
    system("cls");
    cout<<opc;
    if(opc > 0 && opc < 4){
        switch(opc){
        case 1://opcion 1 donde el usuario ingrerara los datos
            cout<<"------------INGRESAR DATOS------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"Digite la cantidad de datos a ingresar"<<endl;
            cin>>to;
            system("cls");
            
            if(to>0){
                for(int i; i<to; i++){
                    cout<<"Digite el numero "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
                    cin>>dato;
                    insertarCola(frente, fin, dato);
                    system("cls");
                }
            }else{
                cout<<"FAVOR DE INGRESAR UN NUMERO MAYOR A 0"<<endl;
            }
            for(int i; i<to; i++){
                cout<<"Digite el numero "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
                cin>>dato;
                insertarCola(frente, fin, dato);
                system("cls");
            }
            cout<<"\tElementos insertados correctamente\n";
            break;
            
        case 2:
            cout<<"\n----------------DATOS----------------"<<endl;
            while(frente != NULL){
                supCola(frente, fin, dato);
                if(frente != NULL){
                    cout<<dato<<"|";
                }else{
                    cout<<dato<<"|"<<endl;
                }
            }
            break;
            
        case 3:
            cout<<"Hasta la proxima, usuario :D";
            break;
        }
    }else{
        cout<<"OPCION INVALIDA, INGRESE NUMEROS"<<endl;
    }
    
}while(opc != 3);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Aqui van las estructuras de las funciones de la cola en el codigo

```
void insertarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, int n){
    Nodo * nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo -> dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo -> sig = NULL;
    
    if(colaVacia(frente)){
        frente = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        fin -> sig = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    fin = nuevo_nodo;
}

bool colaVacia(Nodo *frente){
    return (frente == NULL)? true : false;
}


void supCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, int &n){
    n = frente -> dato;
    Nodo *aux = frente;
    
    if(frente == fin){
        frente = NULL;
        fin = NULL;
    }else{
        frente = frente -> sig;
    }
    
    delete aux;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda inicializar tus variables. En el for no iniciaste la variable `i`.